# Query SSIS Catalog Environment Reference when SSISDB is in High Availability

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to deploy a bunch of SQL Jobs which call SSIS packages to different environments (Test,UAT,Prod).  UAT and Prod are using High Availability and the SSISDB is in an Availability Group.

I have each job scripted and I can dynamically inject the server name the script is deploying on so the SQL Job Step which calls the package references the current server and the proxy account for that environment.  Each job will get deployed to each HA Replica and then have step 1 detect if the server is the active replica and only call the package if it is the active node.

My final step and where I'm stuck is to get each SSIS job step to dynamically select the SSIS Environment that the package should use when called from the job.

My query to get that is below and works fine if my job deploy script runs on the same server where the SSISDB is the active replica.

select @ReferenceID = reference_id from ssisdb.internal.environment_references WHERE environment_name = @MyEnvironment

Once I have the ReferenceID, I will then use it in the SSIS Job Step when calling the package

@command=N'/ISSERVER ""\SSISDB\ProjectName\ProjectSubfolder\MyPackage.dtsx"" /SERVER TheServerName /Par ""$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)"";1 /Par **/ENVREFERENCE @ReferenceID** ""$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E',

the problem is, when running my job deployment is that I can only get the EnvrionmentReferenceID if the SSISDB database is active on the same server I'm deploying my job on.

Is there any other way to solve this apart from setting up linked servers between each HA Replica?

Comment: Do you mean SSISDB is in a different AG than your user databases? You mentioned you detect "if the server is the active replica" but I think you mean "database is the primary replica" since each AG is independent of the others.

Comment: I mean that when you deploy a SQL Job you connect to the specific server because MSDB can't go into an HA so you deploy your job to all replicas in your HA Group.

But, only one of those servers will have an SSISDB in a queryable state so if I need to get the Environment Reference ID, I can't.  I need to run a query against either the other host or the listener to get the EnvReferenceID

Yes, to clarify your point, when detecting the active server in the job step, I'm checking that the job is running on the server with an active SSISDB, so yes, I'm checking the database.

Comment: Not sure I understand then. If the job short-circuits and doesn't execute the package on secondary nodes, why do you need to get the env config from SSISDB when the job runs on secondary nodes?

Comment: It's not about the execution of the job. That works fine.  This is about the Deployment/Creation of the job.  When I run my Create Job script on the server that doesn't have the active SSISDB on it, I cannot get the EnvrionmentReferenceID for to set the Job Step Command